# Rails delete links not working after upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, destroy

With rails 2.3.8 I had

```
= link_to 'old_Delete', link_path(@link), :confirm => 'Are you sure?',  
:method => :delete
```

With rails 3.1.8 this no longer works, no error and the log just shows a show request.

I tried changing it to

```
= link_to 'Delete', link_path(@link), method: :delete, 
data: { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }
```

but that didn't help either.

How can I have a delete link that works.

I created a new app (rails 3.2.7) with a 'post' resource to see how links look in a new app.

The link generated for that was:

```
= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

but when I try to use that format, replacing post (Post resource, model, etc.) with @link, the link instance that I am using elsewhere on the page, i.e.

```
= link_to 'Destroy', @link, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

It doesn't work (no error).

I tried saving rails.js in my public/javascripts folder (I have assest compilation turned off) and including  `config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)` in my config/application.rb but it didn't help, still seeing gets and no deletes happening.

Comment: I didn't personally have any issues with this when upgrading, but the error you're getting in your last example is because you're using a local variable instead of the instance variable `@link`

Comment: changed to @link, didn't help, just a show gets processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said you probably have a typo, `link` vs `@link`.  But the reason the delete stopped working is probably centered around the change to UJS.  Long answer, google "rails change to ujs in 3.0".  Short answer, make sure your app is loading `rails.js`  from an appropriate ujs helper provider, such as https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Make sure that, along with your other changes you change:

```
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

to

```
= javascript_include_tag :defaults
```

Comment: yes I believe this is the issue though I have't managed to get it working trying to set ujs correctly, not sure of the config combinations to do it.  btw, right now I have turned off asset compilation while I focus on getting the app working without it.

Comment: (+1) ok checking that now.  If it gives me the answer I'll give you an accept.

Comment: actually before I watched much I looked at the railscast and changed the javascript include from application to default and that finally worked!  I added this to your answer and will acccept it.

Answer (score 0):

In the last approach is your variable "link" or "@link"? Could you try using the later one?

Comment: Thanks, yes, @link, I changed it and it didn't help, only a get request is sent and the record isn't deleted.